# Carousel Images are not loading unless I resize the window

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I have been spending hours and hours trying to find a solution to this but no luck.

I am using a Carousel and setting the images through a javascript file. However, what's funny is when I load the page, only the first image comes up as desired and the other images (2nd, 3rd....) only show up when I resize the window, and after that everything works fine.

Here' my HTML

```js
(function() {
var type='auto';
  console.log(type);
  for(var i=1; i < 9; i++){
     var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
     newDiv.id = 'sample-image-carousel-element'+i;
     newDiv.className = 'swiper-slide';
     document.getElementById('sample-image-carousal').appendChild(newDiv);
     var newImage = document.createElement('img');
     newImage.id = 'sample-image-carousel-element-image'+i;
     newImage.src = 'assets/img/dc_website/portfolio_images/'+type+'/'+type+'_'+i+'.jpg';
     document.getElementById('sample-image-carousel-element'+i).appendChild(newImage);
  }

})();
```

```css
.portfolio-details-slider img {
  width: 100%;
}
.portfolio-details-slider{
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  border: 1px solid #4154f1;
  background-color: #4154f1;
}
.swiper-container{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  z-index:1
}
.swiper-slide {
  opacity: .3;
}
.swiper-slide img {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.swiper-slide img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section >
<div class="row gy-4">

    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="portfolio-details-slider swiper-container">
        <div id="sample-image-carousal" class=" swiper-wrapper align-items-center">

        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script src="assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Also, important to note that I am using the Swiper bundle CDN's of which are

I've tried adding the max-width and height properties from other answers but not helpful. Any pointers on what I could do to fix this?

Another interesting observation is that when I add the images to the DOM in HTML itself, it works as expected.

Comment: I guess Swiper initializes as soon as it is loaded, so there is a chance it initializes before all images have been appended to the dom. On resize swiper re-evaluates the page, so it finds all images then. Try to initialize Swiper manually after having created all image elements. https://swiperjs.com/get-started#initialize-swiper

Comment: @HansSpieß Thanks a ton! That was the issue, I moved the initialisation after loading the images. If you would post this as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as the answer.

Comment: You can always answer your own question :) Glad it works!

Answer (score 0):

Are there any screen size specific lines of css? Does it show the additional images when you reach a specific window size?

```
        @media screen and (max-width: 1680px) {

            html {
                font-size: 12pt;
            }

        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {

            html {
                font-size: 11pt;
            }

        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 360px) {

            html {
                font-size: 10pt;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work. But I got the solution based on @Hans Spieß 's comment.

Answer (score 0):

With some help and nudge from @Hans Spieß, I figured that Swiper initialized the carousel element as soon as the page loaded (before I loaded the images) which was in a separate `js` file. On resize, Swiper re-evaluated the page, and found all images then.

To solve this, I moved the part of the code that had the initialise statement after the `js` code mentioned in the question and got the desired result!